# How to Print HTML table with same header

Tags: html

Hi all I'm facing a problem with printing pages.I want to have same header on all the pages im printing.I read several answers from stack seems no straigt forward answer.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add a stylesheet for the printing of the page.

```
<link type="text/css" href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
```

Then create a div with your hidden print-only header.

```
<div class="printOnly">Header</div>
```

Hide the `printOnly` div in your regular CSS file.

```
.printOnly { display: none; }
```

In your print.css, do whatever you need to do to your div. This is also where you would hide otherwise visible properties.

```
.printOnly { /* Style */ }
```

This is how I managed print styles.

So, if you have a div called `normalHeader` that you want gone when you print, simply set the style to `display: none;` on the print.css file.

Comment: will this print on all the pages?

Comment: Hi, it will work on any page that it is included on. If you're happy with my answer, please feel free to mark it as your chosen answer. :)

Comment: thank you for they feeback.but i dont want to put header manully on each page.i want it automaticaly.I think your approach will not work.sorry.